# jquery datepicker creates unnecessary whitespaces

Tags: css, jquery-ui-datepicker

the jquery datepicker functions very fine. It's just that the size is too big. I tried:

```
ui-datepicker{
font-size:10px;}
```

to resize it but turned out having unnecessary whitespaces above and below each row. How to remove it? I'm just new to css.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You have to give `padding: 0` to remove gaps

Comment: I tried it but still same result.

Answer (score 0):

In your example `ui-datepicker` is missing a dot. Try changing `font-size` for following: `.ui-datepicker` or `.ui-datepicker table`

On demo site http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/ font size works fine and the day cells scale accordingly to the defined font-size. Go to that page and test using the developer toolbar in your browser (e.g. Firebug in Firefox). Using such developer tools allows you to change CSS and view changes directly.